# StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest

Tags: java

Tengo un control para asegurar que clase me esta llegando

```
if (file instanceof org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile)
```

Pero tengo otro tipo de clase que me puede llegar, haciendo un file.getClass().getName()

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile
```

Pero cuando pongo el if, no entra en la condición

```
if (file instanceof org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile 
|| file instanceof org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.StandardMultipartFile) {
```

Comment: Yo una vez me encontré con una situación similar, en la que también utilizaba `instanceof` para comprobar. Mi solución fue comprobar directamente que las clases fuesen igual: `if (file.getClass().equals(CommonsMultipartFile.class)) {`